# How to prevent on page refresh duplicate data insertion in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How to prevent on page refresh duplicate data insertion in WordPress ?

Comment: Not Cleared question.Please explain it in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that on form submission you are trying to insert data into the Wordpress database based on what was submitted to the form?

If this is the case then you should create one page that the form posts to and process the data (this may be the same page that contains the form) and once the data has been processed and inserted correctly you use `wp_redirect()` to redirect the user to a success page. for example...

```
<?php
//All your code that validates the form and processes the information

//if all is correct then redirect to success page
if( $validation == true ) {
    wp_redirect( bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/success' );
    exit;
}
```

Then you can create a page called 'success' that contains a nice little message telling the user that the form worked correctly.

Hope that helps

Regards

Dan